# Sending data and columns to react-table as prop

Tags: reactjs

I have a page who sends columns and data to a component with React-Tables:

Page:

```
import MOCK_DATA from "../Components/Tables/ExpensesIndexTable/Mock data/MOCK_DATA.json";
import { COLUMNS } from "../Components/Tables/ExpensesIndexTable/Columns/expenses_index_columns.js";
export const Index = () => {
    return (
        <div class="table-responsive-md">
           <BasicTable columns={COLUMNS} data={MOCK_DATA}/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Component:

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import { useTable } from "react-table";
// import MOCK_DATA from "../Mock data/MOCK_DATA.json";
// import { COLUMNS } from "../Columns/expenses_index_columns.js";
export const BasicTable = ({COLUMNS, MOCK_DATA}) => {
    const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, []);
    const data  = useMemo(() => MOCK_DATA, []);
    const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
        useTable({
          columns,
          data,
        });

    return (
        <table
            {...getTableProps()}
            className="table table-hover table-bordered"
        >
            <thead>
                {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                    <tr
                        {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}
                        className="text-center"
                    >
                        {headerGroup.headers.map((col) => (
                            <th {...col.getHeaderProps()}>
                                {col.render("Header")}
                            </th>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                {rows.map((row) => {
                    prepareRow(row);
                    return (
                        <tr {...row.getRowProps()} className="text-center">
                            {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                                return (
                                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                                        {cell.render("Cell")}
                                    </td>
                                );
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    );
                })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
};
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

If I insted of getting the columns and data on the component class as a prop, I use with the import, I don't have this problem.
How can I send data and columns from the page to the component and render those props ok?

EDIT:
Columns file:

```
import { format } from "date-fns";

export const COLUMNS = [
    {
        Header: "Id",
        accessor: "id",
    },
    {
        Header: "Descripcion",
        accessor: "description",
    },
    {
        Header: "Fecha",
        accessor: "date",
        Cell: ({value}) => {return format(new Date(value), 'dd/MM/yyyy')}
    },
    {
        Header: "Monto",
        accessor: "amount",
    },
    {
        Header: "Moneda",
        accessor: "currency",
    },
];
```

MOCK_DATA file (some rows only):

```
[
    {"id":1,"description":"Monkfish - Fresh","date":"2023-09-25T23:26:28Z","amount":82762.98,"currency":"Rupiah","wasInstantPayment":false,"type":true,"status":false},
    {"id":2,"description":"Chocolate - Pistoles, White","date":"2023-09-09T02:30:02Z","amount":70583.09,"currency":"Afghani","wasInstantPayment":false,"type":false,"status":true},


...]
```

Comment: Can you show me 
../Components/Tables/ExpensesIndexTable/Columns/expenses_index_columns.js
?

Comment: Your code is exactly identical as the official example code, so can be sure that its 100% not `BasicTable`'s problem, but the `MOCK_DATA` and `COLUMNS`.  Pls double check with the official example and see if the data you are passing in follows the same format https://codesandbox.io/s/tannerlinsley-react-table-basic-ewm82

Comment: As I said, when I use the MOCK_DATA and COLUMNS imported directly on the component it works fine (are the same files as  imported on the page).

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Index you pass `MOCK_DATA` props with the name of `data`, so in the `BasicTable` component you have to use it with the same name of `data`, but you use `MOCK_DATA` also passing props is case sensitive so `COLUMNS` also should be lower case when using the props inside `BasicTable` component

```js
import MOCK_DATA from "../Components/Tables/ExpensesIndexTable/Mock data/MOCK_DATA.json";
import { COLUMNS } from "../Components/Tables/ExpensesIndexTable/Columns/expenses_index_columns.js";
export const Index = () => {
    return (
        <div class="table-responsive-md">
           <BasicTable columns={COLUMNS} data={MOCK_DATA}/> // <== USING 'data' to pass props
        </div>
    );
};
```